# In Rails, how should I get the new session value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

In java script, I use the ajax to send a post request to the controller to update the session.
For example:

```
def update_session_top
  session[:top] = params[:top]
end
```

But after the updating action is done, in java script, I still can't get the latest the session value because the page is not reloaded. I don't know how should I retrieve the latest one without reloading the page.

Comment: What do you mean? How are you accessing/using the session value in the template? Do you just need to update part of the DOM based on the new value?

Comment: My original intention was trying some interaction between client and server. I can get some parameters like(var topping = data.getValue())  in java script, but I can't use the latest topping value in template, like <%= People.where(status:topping)%>. So I just trying to update the session value by ajax, then make use of the session value in template. But right now, I find it doesn't work if I don't refresh the page. So I don't know where is the better way if I don't redirect to another link.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you set the session value then either render a partial into the div, or get data back in JSON and handle it entirely in JS, via Ajax?

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton, I think the session is not a good idea for my case. Right now, I use the link_to function to redirect another link. I'll try your suggestion of JS.